# Why does Python extend output [[...]]

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

My lecturer has set several questions on python, and this one has got me confused, I dont understand what is happening.

```
x = [[]]
x[0].extend(x)
```

Python tells me, after running this that x is `[[...]]`, what does the `...` mean?

I get even more confused when the result of the following is just `[[]]`

```
y = [] # equivalent to x[0]
x = [[]]
y.extend(x)
```

If `y` is calculated to be `[[]]` shouldn't `x` be calculated to simply being `[[[]]]`?

What is extend doing? and what does the `...` mean?

Comment: Because `x` references itself, `str(x)` is an infinite loop. Its nice that python catches it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `...` indicates that the list contains a recursive loop, i.e., at some level something contains itself.  This is because you extended `x` with `x`, so you essentially put `x` inside itself.

There is no `...` in the second example because `y` is a distinct object.  Although it happens to be *equal* to `x[0]` in that both are empty lists, they are not the same empty list.

Comment: So by extending `x[0]` with `x`, its creating a reference to `x` at `x[0]`, rather than copying the data that `x` contains to `x[0]`? is that right?

Comment: @CGA1123: Basically, yes.  (More specifically, it is creating a reference to `x[0]` inside the list at `x[0]`, since `extend` adds the contents of its argument, not the argument itself.  But you are right that it is creating a reference to the same object, not copying data, and that is the key.)